# converting from a list to dictionary for a word2vec model

Tags: python, dictionary, nlp, word2vec

i have a huge corpus of data in my my text file that i want to train for skip gram model.
i have split  the data from file into list
now i want to count the words with their number of occurrence and make a dictionary ,give the word as key to the dictionary and frequency as the value.here is a snippet of my code

```
with open("enwik8","r") as data:
    words=data.read().split()   

vocabulary_size = 5000


  count = [['UNK', -1]]
  count.extend(collections.Counter(words).most_common(vocabulary_size - 1))
count.extend(collections.Counter(words).most_common(vocabulary_size - 1))
```

i have succesfully made a list with the words and their frequency upto first most common 50000 words,now i need to feed them to dictionary,key as a word and value as freq.

```
dictionary = dict()
for word, _ in count:
```

can anyone help me through??

Comment: What's `count`?

Comment: @Goyo srry ,i missed one line of code.it is a list.

Comment: You want `dict(count)`.

Comment: i am sorry if i was unable to explain my question.i made a list ,which is in the form[('words','frequency')] and this is upto 50000 most common words.now i want to change this list to dictionary-{'words':'frequency'},key as the word and freq as the value.@Goyo

Comment: `dict(count)` should do that, it does for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have already a list of words, here is how you draw dictionary out of it as per your need:

```
word_dict = dict()
for word_count in words:
    if word_count[0] not in word_dict:
        word_dict[word_count[0]] = word_count[1]
```

your list contains tuples, so `word_dict[word_count[0]]`, so I am placing first item of tuple that is word as a `key` in dictionary and second item `word_count[1]` in tuple which is count as `value` to that `key`

Comment: i need to do that only on the list 'count' because i have my refined words in the list in the format [('word','no. of times it is in the corpus')]

Comment: can you please explain me the meaning of this line." word_dict[word_count[0]] = word_count[1]" i only know basic dictionary.

Comment: posted explanation as part of the answer